# Where can I find a free or open source C++ library to do BCD math?

Tags: c++, open-source, bcd

Where can I find a free or open source C++ library to do [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) math?

Comment: You should ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ your question would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.  I just wrote this, and am making it public domain.

It converts an unsigned bcd to an unsigned int and vice-versa.  Use bcd2i() to convert your BCDs to unsigned ints, do whatever math you need, then use i2bcd() to bring the numbers back to BCD.

```
unsigned int bcd2i(unsigned int bcd) {
    unsigned int decimalMultiplier = 1;
    unsigned int digit;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (bcd > 0) {
        digit = bcd & 0xF;
        i += digit * decimalMultiplier;
        decimalMultiplier *= 10;
        bcd >>= 4;
    }
    return i;
}

unsigned int i2bcd(unsigned int i) {
    unsigned int binaryShift = 0;  
    unsigned int digit;
    unsigned int bcd = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
        digit = i % 10;
        bcd += (digit << binaryShift);
        binaryShift += 4;
        i /= 10;
    }
    return bcd;
}
// Thanks to EmbeddedGuy for bug fix: changed init value to 0 from 1 


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int tests[] = {81986, 3740, 103141, 27616, 1038, 
               56975, 38083, 26722, 72358, 
                2017, 34259};

int testCount = sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]);

cout << "Testing bcd2i(i2bcd(test)) on 10 cases" << endl;
for (int testIndex=0; testIndex<testCount; testIndex++) {
    int bcd = i2bcd(tests[testIndex]);
    int i = bcd2i(bcd);
    if (i != tests[testIndex]) {
        cout << "Test failed: " << tests[testIndex] << " >> " << bcd << " >> " << i << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
cout << "Test passed" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @levis501. One advantage of BCD is that numbers are of unlimited size unlike integers, so converting to int to perform math functions would be limiting. +1 for very handy code.

Comment: Just curious, how are your BCD's stored?  With a small modification, the code could just as easily convert to/from memory array of data, and then apply an arbitrary precision library to do the math.

Comment: Good list of arbitrary-precision math libs at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: Thanks. I think an arbitrary precision library will be a big help.

Comment: @Richard Brightwell: There's nothing about "BCD" that requires arbitrary precision. If your ultimate goal is arbitrary precision, then use an arbitrary precision library such as GMP (and internally it will use base 2^16 or base 2^32 or something convenient, but not base 10).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, conversion errors are not always acceptable. As errors can't be avoided, BCD computations are sometimes a must. XBCD_Math, for example, is a fully featured BCD floating point library.

Answer (score 0):

Math is math - it doesn't matter is you add or multiply in base 2, in base 10 or in base 16: the answer is always the same.

I don't know how your input and output would be coded, but all you should need is convert from BCD to integer, do the math just like you normally would, and at the end re-convert from integer to BCD.

Comment: The BCD number may be larger than an integer. Therefor the need to perform math functions directly on values stored in BCD format.

Comment: Here is match library to deal with "big" numbers: http://www.ttmath.org/.  You can also use boost::int64_t if 64 bits is sufficient.  There is no need to use BCD for this - except it may be a bit easier to verify the calculations by hand if you do your own implementation :)

Comment: Or this library: http://gmplib.org/.  I don't have any experience with either.

Comment: Thanks Warpin. I think one of the arbitrary precision math libraries combined with Levis' code will do the trick. +1 for your big math libraries.

Comment: BCD arithmetic is mostly useful when the amount of processing required to convert between binary and decimal is comparable to or greater than the amount necessary to do the actual calculation. For example, if you want to write a function that calculates the number of 7s in the decimal representation of 2^n for n between 1 and 50,000,000, you're likely better off doing a bunch of additions in BCD than doing a bunch of binary-to-decimal conversions, especially considering cache effects and opportunities for parallel computation.